# How do I create a custom tax class in Magento?

Tags: php, magento

I was wondering if I can set a custom taxclass in magento.
It needs to be a specific calculation for the price.

The calculation is as follows:

(Price×1.30+10)×1.19 = Final Price

The tax in The Netherlands is 19% so that's why the price is times 1.19.
The 1.30+10 is just to up the purchase cost.

Then if possible the price needs to round off to 5 minus 5 cents.
Meaning if the final price will be 46,50 the price will round off upwards to 49,95

For 32,30 the price will become 34,95

For 19,20 the price will become 19,95
Etc.

Can anyone help me with this. The most important thing is inputting the main calculation the round off is a bit less important for now.

I know this can be done quite easily in php but I don't know how to easily implement it into magento.

Thank you.

Comment: and you can't create the tax rule from admin for this? why?

Comment: Magento tax system uses percentages only by default. It looks like the  adding $10 is what is going to throw him off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put in a new WEBSITE with tax setup for the netherlands. Use GEOIP for those Dutch customers to only see these store prices. Do all your price calculationings in Excel and import the prices into this secondary store view/website.